# special characters to accept in secure properties in mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mulesoft, mule4

Need small help. If I use same pattern which are in Host, Port and Username for Password then getting SFTP connection error but if I use password as hard code value as shown in below screenshot(sharing dummy value as password not to show )then connected and file is writing as expected. Can anyone suggest?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBERW.jpg)

Comment: what is the error? Please add to the question in text form, not a screenhost. Please use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason.

Comment: error is 'Could not establish SFTP connection' .  And I added ${secure::test.sftp.pwd} in SFTP connector configuration at Password text box.

Comment: and example password format from properties file is    sample:1234   as :  there in between password SFTP connector is not able to take what ever the value starting from :  till end of the password.   So for easy understand I attached screenshot.

Comment: I am still waiting for the response if anyone can help and sugges

Comment: I am closing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try print the values thru a logger before the ftp connector and verify that whatever you are expecting are coming out of the secure properties. Ideally it should not be the case, but if in case the values are different double check your encryption key, and  also verify if you are properly preparing the encrypted values and adding to the config file.
Also verify if your config environment entry is pointing to the right file where you have added this encryption or if you have overridden value in the runtime configs.

Do not forget to update how you closed and what was your mistake in this thread.

Regards
Mahesh Raja Vandyala